# Separación desigual en jQuery contextMenu con Font Awesome Icons

Tags: jquery

He incluído algunos [íconos](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) al [jQuery ContextMenu](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/) pero la separación que hay entre tales íconos y los que ya trae el ContextMenu, es distinta, haciendo que quede sin uniformidad.

Así es como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si se fijan, los íconos que traje de Font Awesome Icons son el signo menos y el más encerrado en un cuadrado y entre ellos tienen cierta separación distinta al resto de los íconos.

Alguien sabe por qué ocurre y cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente extraje todos mis iconos desde [Font Awesome Icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/), de esa forma ya no hay diferencia en las separaciones, el resultado fue este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La separación que tienen es un tanto menor a la de los iconos que trae el ContextMenu por defecto, entonces es recomendable no mezclarlos, además todos los íconos del ContextMenu están en Font Awesome Icons.

Por cierto, pueden ver cómo añadir estos iconos al JQuery ContextMenu [aquí](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/fontawesome-icons.html).